# Probability Mass Function for Transformation of a Binomial Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let X have a binomial distribution with n trials and probability p of success. What is the pmf of Y ≡|X −2|?

I'm struggling to figure out what the support is for Y. Any tips?

Comment: What's the support of $X$?

Comment: X = 0, 1, 2, 3, …

Comment: How many successes can you have at most?

Comment: If there are n trials, then at most there are n successes right?

Comment: Exactly, so $0$ to $n$. Now, we have $Y=|X-2|$. So if X can take the values from $0$ to $n$, what values can $Y$ take? You will need a case distinction. The cases $n=0,1,2,3,4$ are special, for $n\ge 5$ the system is always the same.

Comment: So Y = 0, 1, 2, ..., n-2 but Y = 1, 2 are special cases because they can occur twice. For example, Y = 1 when X = 1, 3. Does that mean Y ~ Bin(n-2, p) when y = 0, 3, 4, ..., n-2 but I'm not so sure when y = 1, 2

Answer (score 1):

The cases $n=0,\dots,3$ can be done by hand, but are also covered by the below (using that $\binom{n}{x}=0$ unless $0\le x\le n$).

Recall that $\mathbb P(X=x)=\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$. For $Y=|X-2|$ we have $\mathbb P(Y=y)=0$ for $y<0$, $\mathbb P(Y=0)=\mathbb P(X=2)=\binom{n}{2}p^2(1-p)^{n-2}$, $\mathbb P(Y=1)=\mathbb P(X=1)+\mathbb P(X=3)=\binom{n}{1}p^1(1-p)^{n-1}+\binom{n}{3}p^3(1-p)^{n-3}$, $\mathbb P(Y=2)=\mathbb P(X=0)+\mathbb P(X=4)=\binom{n}{0}p^0(1-p)^{n-0}+\binom{n}{4}p^4(1-p)^{n-4}$, and $\mathbb P(Y=y)=\mathbb P(X=y+2)=\binom{n}{y+2}p^{y+2}(1-p)^{n-(y+2)}$ otherwise (which implies that $\mathbb P(Y=y)=0$ for $y>n-2$ because then $\binom{n}{y+2}=0$). Notice that this distribution does not have a dedicated name (most distributions don't), and that there are also no simplifications for $\mathbb P(Y=1)$, $\mathbb P(Y=2)$ in general (next to $\binom{n}{1}=n$ and $p^1=p$ and the likes).
Thus, you might say that $Y$ is "almost" the shifted binomial $X-2$ with a slightly different behavior at the very left tail.